# Codeigniter 3 - Make URLs case insensitive

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, config, controllers

With CI3 released controllers must now be Ucword-style (for whatever reason). No problem changing these, but upgrading any site now leads to 404s wherever it's applicable (which is pretty much everywhere).
Is there a way to make it so the old URLs still work (in addition)?  Ie I have a controller 'Admin.php" the index() fn of which used to be called

```
   http://example.com/admin
```

now it must be called

```
       http://example.com/Admin
```

Is there a way to have both work (on CentOS). Maybe via Apache rewrite and/or config?

Comment: Did you upgrade your CI projects to the latest version? If you did it properly, check your routes config, they should be like this `$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';`

Answer (score 0):

You can set your routes in : 
**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

You can set your Controller as following code in controller.

**application/controllers/Admin.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model(array('admin_model'));
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->template->view('admin/index');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If case insensitive routes are required, do below changes to `URI.php`

**Location of File:** `system/core/URI.php`

Find  `$this->_parse_request_uri()`  and replace it with `strtolower($this->_parse_request_uri())`